# What can be a use case for @Transient annotation from Spring Security Core?

Tags: spring, spring-security

The official documentation for the `@Transient` states: (Link [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/Transient.html))

> A marker for Authentications that should never be stored across requests, for example a bearer token authentication

I understand that `@Transient` should be used when we do not want to persist any details.
One such example that the documentation mentions is for bearer token authentication which makes sense.

What can be a general rule of thumb for situtation(s) where `@Transient` should be used?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty much what is written in the Javadocs. The transient authentication tokens indicate to the filter chain, specifically the
`HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`, whether or not the token ought
to be persisted across requests.

Implementations of `SecurityContextRepository` may choose to not persist
tokens that are marked with `@Transient` in the same way
that `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` does.

There are more details in the [related issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5481).